# How could octopuses evolve a complex society

Tags: science-based, biology, evolution, intelligence

The title is a bit misleading, but let me explain.

Octopuses are seen to be quite intelligent, capable of solving complex puzzles, manipulate tools, and are even capable of becoming bored. This Caught my interest, which lead me to question whether or not octopuses could evolve and develop towards a human like society, pretty much in a way that’s close to building city’s or neighborhoods, forming jobs and using science and math.

**what environmental factors would make octopuses evolve and develop human like societies**

To reiterate, the question is asking what environmental factors would lead to octopuses evolving the intelligence to go up on land (optional), form primitive societies, like tribes, and then form an even more complex societies. Essentially what is monkey to human and octopus to intelligent octopus

Answer (score 3):

### All we know is that technological intelligence required for societal complexity is exceedingly rare

**There is a distinction between simple intelligence and technological intelligence**. Technological Intelligence is required to sustain complex societies because of the ability to enable large groups such as within cities, complex social gatherings and procedures, comprehension of and awareness, and eventual manipulation, of complex social and physical surroundings.

In contrast **many animals already display simple intelligence** - and this includes us. You can be individually smart, but that does not allow you to create submarines and exist underwater, or the reverse for your octopus.

In fact, humans have shown only technological intelligence recently - within the last 30,000 or so years. Prior to that, there were many hundreds of thousands of years where, even though physiologically we were much the same, **for a long time humans had little or no technological capability**.

So what changed? Many think it was the invention of fire, and the increased ability to allow social structures, the invention of farming to allow brains to consider concepts other than survival, or the grouping of tribes.

The real answer is likely just simply chance, with **exactly the right sequence of improvements and transfer of knowledge** combined with the environmental space or need to preserve such knowledge. Dinosaurs have existed for over 250 million years on this planet, yet for all that time showed no sign of Technological Intelligence. They may have individually been intelligent, but this indicates to us that it is very rare to achieve cities, devices to allow them to exist in environments they are not suited to.

So for your octopuses:

- The need to be social, and *require social structures to survive*. Humans are terrible at everything, their young defenceless for a long time, and innately competitive against each other. Your octopuses may need these traits first.
- But even that is not enough, as that would get you only to 'monkey' stage. For the next leap *you need something similar to fire* - how to enable octopuses to exist where they don't like to be at the same time as a competitive tribal structure. Perhaps they can create structures or dig channels that enable them to exist in ponds close to shore.
- Once these tribes are formed and the divisions in population created, you need a whole series of Cooperative or Competitive *events that lead to social complexity where societies that are more complex are more successful*. This may be random, as studies have shown fire was invented at least 60 times before 'catching on', but you need a way for octopuses to be able to teach their children in social and physical prowess.
- Now you are starting to get there, but you still need ways for your Octopus to record information (ie writing), read it (ie language or art), sustain large numbers (underwater farming) coupled with hierarchal and institutional structures (governance, education, laws) to enable complex societies.

Only then can Octopuses invent a reverse submarine to exist on land. All this may indicate it is very rare indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The most massive problem to overcome is the very short lifespan of octopii and the r reproductive strategy that results. Octopii mate, lay huge clutches of eggs and then essentially starve themselves to death sitting over the eggs until they hatch. There is literally no way for Octopii to gather experience, pass on knowledge or any of the other sorts of things we believe are necessary for civilizations to grow and adapt.

So the first thing that needs to be done is some sort of genetic mutation which creates a species of octopus which lives significantly longer than they do today. With the ability to gain experience and living long enough to pass it on, an octupus culture and civilization has the ability to start and to grow.

Even better for the Octopii would be a concurrent change from r to K reproductive strategies, where they hatch relatively few offspring and devote a portion of their lives to raising them, passing on skills and knowledge.

However, the r strategy works for octopii becasue they live in a very dangerous environment and outside of their rather alien intelligence, have no natural offensive weapons or defensive armour to protect them. Being at risk of being torn apart by predatory fish means using their intelligence to hide or mimic, and broadcasting huge numbers of offspring in the hope that some of them will survive to pass on their genes. Growing defensive shells is out (Octopii are intelligent *becasue* their long ago ancestors ditched the shells - their close relatives are molluscs), so the evolutionary movement towards a complex society will depend on a mutation that increases lifespans and tips the balance towards a K reproductive strategy.